# How to prevent Camera app to change orientation to landscape in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I've used the camera native app through my app for taking picture. I've used the below code for display the camera app in portrait mode only.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION,
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

But, it's not working with the above code.

Any suggestions will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the orientation of an external application that you launch, so there is no way to do this. 
But you could create your own camera activity.

Answer (score 0):

considering your mCamera as your Camera, you can create your camera activity, set à cameraPReview and set the preview in protrait mode by adding `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` before starting preview

here is an example for camera preview in a FrameLayout in potrait mode:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            if(mCamera!=null){
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();}
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

and you set the preview from your MainActivity like below :

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(getApplicationContext(), camera);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
```

Comment: Thanks @E.Abdel ! This code you suggested for Custom Camera right? But i want to make use of native camera app.

Comment: you can't change configurations of another app, try to create your own camera activity it's easy